# java array returning min

Tags: java

hi I am writing this array in order to read in 30 integers and read out the min and max. I have solved the max but the minimum is not working, all help is appreciated, As stated i have solved the max , but the minimum is not working

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Uppgift1
{
public static void main(String args[])throws IOException
{
BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader
        (new InputStreamReader (System.in));

        int antal = 0; 
        int summa = 0;
        double medel = 0;
        int min;
        int max = 0;
                System.out.print("Hur manga tal vill du mata in(max 30)? ");
                antal = Integer.parseInt(stdin.readLine());

        int [] array = new int[antal];

        for(int i = 0; i<antal; i++){
        array[i] = Integer.parseInt(stdin.readLine());
        summa = summa +array[i];
        medel = summa / antal; 


        }
                System.out.println("summan av talen är "+summa);
                System.out.println("medel av alla tal är "+medel);

        for (int i = 0; i < antal; i++) 
      {
        while(array[i]>max)
            { 
        max=array[i];
          }
            } 


            System.out.println("max numret är " + max);


        for (int i = 0; i < antal; i++) 
            {
                while(array[i]<min)
                    { 
                        min=array[i];
                    }
            } 


            System.out.println("min numret är " + min);





}}
```

Comment: Initialize `min` with `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. Moreover, I would replace the `while`s in the `for` loops with `if`s.

Answer (score 5):

The `min` starts off at zero, so it compares lower than any positive number the user enters.

In general, you start off the minimum high and your maximum low before entering a loop. This sacrifices two numbers from the available range, which is usually OK.  Alternatively, you could set both `min` and `max` to the initial element of the sequence.

The other problem is your use of `while` instead of `if`: it's not hurting the result, but it does hurt readability a lot.

Finally, you can search for both the `min` and the `max` in the same loop.

Answer (score 1):

do this for calculating min and max
suppose you have array called numbers.
initialise variables min,max as given below

```
int min = numbers[0];
int max = numbers[0];

for(int i=1; i< numbers.length(); i++) {
  if(min>numbers[i]) {
     min = numbers[i];
  }
  if(max<numbers[i]) {
    max = numbers[i];
  }
}

System.out.println("Max Is : " + max);
System.out.println("Min Is : " + min);
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your `min` variable with the largest possible integer (`Integer.MAX_VALUE`).  Any number that's smaller than this will be found.

Initialize your `max` variable with the smallest possible integer (`Integer.MIN_VALUE`).  Any number that's larger than this will be found.

Answer (score 0):

```
max= 0;
min=0;
for (int i = 0; i < antal; i++)  {
    max = Math.max(max, array[i]);
    min = Math.min (min, array[i]);
}
```